# jquery: How to pass form element info to another function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, function

I am trying to do some things on a form element blur. The problem I'm having is passing the element's info such as ID, class, etc to a second function. I've simplified it down for this example:

```
function otherfunction() {
    var inputID = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(inputID);
}


$(".formelement").blur(function () { 

// Do some stuff here

otherfunction();

});
```

Of course, the alert box says that the inputID is undefined. How can I get the element's info passed to the otherfunction?

Comment: You can simply use `this.id` to access the ID of an element instead of `$(this).attr('id')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the input as an argument:

```
function otherfunction(el) {
    var inputID = $(el).attr("id");
    alert(inputID);
}


$(".formelement").blur(function () {
    // Do some stuff here

    otherfunction(this);
});
```

Or, use `Function.prototype.apply`:

```
function otherfunction() {
    var inputID = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(inputID);
}


$(".formelement").blur(function () {
    // Do some stuff here

    otherfunction.apply(this);
});
```

Comment: WOW can't believe I could not find the answer to that! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Use [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) in case of:

```
$(".formelement").blur($.proxy(otherfunction, this));
```

And otherwise javascript's [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
$(".formelement").blur(function () { 

    // Do some stuff here

    otherfunction.call(this); // or otherfunction.apply(this); 
});
```

Comment: Sort of... but `$.proxy` doesn't actually invoke the function. It just returns a function that will guarantee the `this` value. You still need to invoke it. Also, you need to pass the function itself instead of a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think u can use like this :

```
function otherfunction(obj) {
    var inputID = $(obj).attr("id");
    alert(inputID); }


$(".formelement").blur(function () { 

otherfunction($(this));

});
```